# Multiple FTP host behind one public IP

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy, ftp

I have two boxes . one ubuntu and one Windows
Both are hosting http and ftp sites
Before they connected to the internet through different IPs so there was no problema, however, we're now down to a single public IP and i have to make both machines availlable without changin ports.

Now since both handle diffrent domains, i've added a virtual host in the ubuntu box that proxy reverses to the Windows box on the required domains

However, when it comes to ftp i am at a loss How can i handle domain A in the ubuntu box and defer domain b to be handled by the Windows box?

I'm using vsftpd in the ubuntu box and IIS in the Windows box

Any help appreciated

Luis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One work-around would be to to let either one of the boxes handle all FTP traffic, where one user uploads to the local file system, and another user to a file share exported from the other server.

Alternatively ditch FTP altogether and use WebDAV, which will allow Name Based virtual hosting.

Comment: Am affraid i'm stuck with ftp for several reasons - wish i wasn't - and as stated in @etherfish's answer, i'd rather not mix the two if i can avoid it

Comment: endede up moving the update to a file share after things changed enough not to be stuck with ftp

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, ftp does not support hostname/DNS based virtualhosting the way http does.

So, if you must have two separate ftp sites then I'd recommend getting an extra external IP address.

If they're not both anonymous ftp sites, you could likely get away with a different chroot for each ftp user.

Good Luck.

Comment: Neither is anonymous - the ubuntu is the main one and the other is used mainly as a program update deployment. I'd rather not mix the two if i can avoid the assle that would be

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm,

### Option 1

Have you tried using SRV records for your FTP servers? You'd need to implement some dns changes, and they'd have to map to internal IP address of the ftp servers, so there would be some NAT'ing involved, but this sounds like the way to go. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRV_record):

```
A Service record (SRV record) is a specification of data in the Domain Name System defining the location, i.e. the hostname and port number, of servers for specified services.
```

and takes the form

```
_service._proto.name. TTL class SRV priority weight port target.
```

So for you I would do something like

```
_ftp._tcp.ftp1.example.com. 3600 IN 0 1 21 ftpserver1.example.com
```

And of course have some way of resolving ftpserver1.example.com into the appropriate IP.

The bad news? Not every client software supports SRV records, so perhaps

### Option 2

You should employ a proxy that listens on port 21 and forwards the traffic to the appropriate ftp server based on the dns name requested.

Comment: One of the domains is registered at DynDNS (left over from a time without static IP) and is embued enough in the companies workflow (freelancers access our systems through it and it would be complex to change that now) that i can't do away with them - but i can't configure SRV for them as far as i know either. The proxy is an option i considered but have no experience with. All i find online is reference to http proxies and configuring browsers for them - any links i could use?

Comment: I have no practical experience setting this up, so I can't be of much help there, but in theory it should be doable while keeping the front facing access the same.